# If $R$ is a positive operator and $R^2 = T^{*}T$, why does this mean we can write $R$ as $\sqrt{T^{*}T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $R$ is a positive operator and $R^2 = T^{*}T$, why does this mean we can write $R$ as $\sqrt{T^{*}T}$? Should I be thinking of the square root of an operator as in the way I think about it when it applies to real numbers?

Comment: How do you define the square root of a matrix?  What requirements do we place on a matrix before taking its square root?  What should $\sqrt{R^2}$ be (i.e. what is the domain of our square root function)?  If $R^2 = T^*T$, then certainly $\sqrt{R^2} = \sqrt{T^*T}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may very well think of positive operators like positive numbers among $\mathbb{C}$. Infact, most of the properties of positive operators are equivalent to the ones in positive numbers. If you are interested, the proof of the fact that there exists a unique positive square root for a positive operator may be found in any standard linear algebra text like [Axler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a functional calculus :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus

I wanted to write this as a comment, but I don't have enough points.